# How to change TeXShop highlighting color during delimiter matching?

Tags: editors, texshop, syntax-highlighting

Could someone explain how to tone down the blood-red default background color that TeXShop uses during delimiter matching? Sadly it's driving me nuts and I need to change it to something more soothing--and that leaves the highlighted text more legible. I've fiddled around in the Preferences/Themes panel and can't seem to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color by going to TeXshop > Preferences > Themes and editing the color value for "Braces" and "Enclosed" in the "Characters" row.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. Turns out I was only changing the opacity and that seems to have no effect. When I change the actual color for "Enclosed", that does it. (Still not sure what "Braces" does.)

Comment: @Dan The "Braces" is the color the {} change to during the highlight (also red by default).